# How to return to app after ShareTargetActivated event finishes?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

If the app is already in background/suspended and *OnShareTargetActivated* event is invoked, it runs in new *ApplicationView* with new window. It works good, but when sharing is finished I would like to return to my main view (previous) of application, which was in background/suspended. Is it possible?

In former builds (10586) of UWP, there was [ShareOperation.DismissUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.sharetarget.shareoperation.dismissui) method which done the job, but starting from 10493 this method is deprecated and doesn't work on all devices. As I've tried [ShareOperation.ReportCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.sharetarget.shareoperation.reportcompleted.aspx) closes share window, but then returns to the app that was a source of shared data, not to the background/suspended view of my app.

Sample scenario: user clicks in my app button 'Find translation in internet', this opens Edge with bing/google translator and my app gets suspended. In Edge user marks some text and clicks share and chooses the app. This fires *OnShareTargetActivated* which starts new *View* of the app, once share is finished (*ReportCompleted*) user is redirected to Edge. I would like somehow to switch to my main (previously suspended) view - I'm able to do this on mobile with usage of *ApplicationViewSwitcher*, however, on desktop it's not possible due to exception you get while trying to access *CoreWindow* of previous view.

Comment: User is supposed to return to the app that is source of shared data, not your app. You may create a copy of your app UI in the newly created share window. Main view is running on a separate UI Thread/Window, I don't think you can show it in the share Window.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Generally I miss this old *DismissUI* method. If I invoke share source from my app (for example edge) and then share some information, the desired behavior is to return to main app. I would like to avoid creating duplicate of main view. There is something like *ApplicationViewSwitcher* - I wonder if somebody has a good solution for that.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz With *ApplicationViewSwitcher* I'm able to return to main view on mobile, but this is not possible on desktop. I wonder if there is a way to do it on any device.

Comment: Looks like you have more info on this than me, but I still don't get the scenario: whether it is your app sharing something or another app sharing something to your app.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Let's assume that user clicks in my app 'search for translation in internet', this fires bing/google translator in Edge, I can mark text and share to my app. Once Edge has been fired, the main view is suspended and after sharing the new view is created (the old one is still present and I would like to bring it back) - I'm able to do this on mobile with the *ApplicationViewSwitcher*, but not on desktop).

Comment: I got it know. The problem is, since you launch Edge normally, going back to your app is up to user (unless you could use the launch for result mechanism). Using share contract in Edge as a way to return to your app seems a little bit odd. IMO the expected design is: user shares data, you call ReportCompleted in share contract, then user manually closes edge and opens your app. However I suggest you include the scenario in the question aswell, maybe an expert knows an answer.